# How to disable whole keyboard in linux?

Tags: debian, keyboard

I want my whole keyboard disabled for some time as I keep my notebook on my laptop keyboard while studying and unnecessarily, many unwanted keys are pressed. But, I don't want to disable the touchpad as I need any one input device.

I have installed ParrotOS (Debian Based).

Please suggest

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard.

Comment: Thank you... That was everything.. If instead of comment, you would have answered, you'd have got my upvote... Although I had to install xinput

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I wasn't sure if it would work for you. I can put together an answer when I get to my computer, so that people can find it better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `xinput float` to disable your keyboard.

As @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answered in https://askubuntu.com/a/178741/905329:

> You can use `xinput` to float the input device under X.
>
> 1. Execute the command `xinput list` to list your input devices.
> 2. Locate `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` and take note of its `id` number; this will be used to disable the keyboard. Also, take note of the number at the end, `[slave keyboard (#)]`; this is the id number of the `master`, which will be used to re-enable your keyboard.
> 3. To disable the keyboard, execute the command `xinput float <id#>`, where `<id#>` is your keyboard's id number. For example, if the `id` was `10`, then the command would be `xinput float 10`.
> 4. To re-enable the keyboard, execute the command `xinput reattach <id#> <master#>`, where `master` is that second number we noted down. So if the number was `3`, you would do `xinput reattach 10 3`.

Comment: I made two bash files, one for disabling the keyboard and one for enabling so that I don't have to connect a keyboard everytime I want to re-enable it...

Comment: Sounds useful. Good thinking!